# comparing 2 files unix

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have 2 scripts `file.txt` and `file2.txt`

file1.txt

```
|col1|col2| 
|name|mandatory|
|age|mandatory| 
|address|mandatory|
|email|mandatory| 
|country|not-mandatory|
```

file2.txt

```
|col1|col2| 
|name|gabrielle| 
|age|| 
|address|nashville| 
|email|Gabrielle@outlook.com| 
|country||
```

I need to create a temporary file to get all the rows in file1 where the column has mandatory . then I need to check if the mentioned mandatory fields are null or not in file2

Expected output:

```
age mandatory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F '|' '
    NR==FNR && $3=="mandatory" {m[$2]++}
    NR>FNR && $3=="" && m[$2] {printf "%s mandatory\n", $2}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Output

```
age mandatory
```

Explanation

`awk` iterates across each line of both files. The record separator is considered to be `|`. That means the first field is always empty.

The first line of the script looks for lines in `file1.txt` (the `NR` Number of Records read so far matches the line number of the current file), where the third field is `mandatory`, and saves the second field in an array.

The second line of the script looks for lines in `file2.txt` (the Number of Records read is more than the line number of the current file) and, when the third field is empty, and it's in the list we created earlier, then we print out the first field's name